# Use of Python in web develpment

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Right now i am learning python and i want to start doing web development with Python.

I wanted to know about the different types of things we can do with python in web development.

Comment: Out of all these, I'm afraid Python is the least important for web development.

Comment: You may have learned HTML and CSS while you were asking this question.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd highly recommend learning HTML, JS, and CSS. It is essential for web development. It should be fairly straightforward though, especially compared to learning python. I expect you'll pick it up quickly.

I'm not sure you'd really understand the underpinnings of frameworks like Django without those first.

I'm sure you can learn it as you go though.

Good luck.